# How do I validate a Numeric character in scala?

Tags: scala

my application takes in a string like this (-110,23,-111.9543633) I need to validate/retrieve inside scala script that the string whether it is Numeric or not?

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to convert to `Int` or `Double`, or rather need to check if a `String` can be converted to a type that has an implicit `Numeric[_]`

Comment: Just suppose my input is coming as "111" so its numeric to i raise a flag saying its numeric, or same in case if input comes like "-78" but if my input comes like "111.67"  I need to raise flag as decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and its working fine:

val s = "-1112.12"
s.isNumeric && (s.contains('.')==false)

Answer (score 13):

Consider `scala.util.Try` for catching possible exceptions in converting a string onto a numerical value, as follows,

```
Try("123".toDouble).isSuccess
Boolean = true

Try("a123".toDouble).isSuccess
Boolean = false
```

As of ease of use, consider this implicit,

```
implicit class OpsNum(val str: String) extends AnyVal {
  def isNumeric() = scala.util.Try(str.toDouble).isSuccess
}
```

Hence

```
"-123.7".isNumeric
Boolean = true

"-123e7".isNumeric
Boolean = true

"--123e7".isNumeric
Boolean = false
```

Comment: try catch for such check is a waste of resources, you can check the string directly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want not only to convert by using `Try(x.toInt)` or `Try(x.toFloat)` but actually want a *validator* that takes a `String` and return `true` iff the passed `String` can be converted to a `A` with `implicit evidence: Numeric[A]`.

Then I would say: Afaik, **no** it is not possible. Especially, since `Numeric` is not *sealed*. That is you can create your own implementations of `Numeric`

Primitive types like `Int, Long, Float, Double` can be easily extracted with a regular expression.